# Distribute a Secret to users without showing it to users [Active Directory, Group Policy]

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I need to distribute a secret token to a group of users, where it would be stored in ODBC configuration in the password field (masked). The goal is to make it accessible for GPO script, but not viewable by users (to reduce chances of leaking).

My question is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013265/distribute-secrets-via-active-directory-group-policy), but as I understand, in that case users will be able to access the secret in the place where it is stored.

What is the best way of achieving that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Group Policy is not the appropriate technology for this requirement.

Comment: I am happy to learn that. What is the appropriate technology for this @GregAskew? Maybe I just rewrite the question and change tags.

Comment: Please give some info on what you are trying to do in the script. Does the script needs access to user-related data or do some user-related data changes?